# Clicking Publish for an ASP.NET Core 2.0 project in Visual Studio 2017 does nothing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, publishing

I'm trying to publish my ASP.NET Core 2.0 web project as I've done several times before, but it's not responding. Clicking publish produces no output whatsoever, no status bar changes, no alerts. It just does nothing:

[image]

What's the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the problem was a corrupted `*.csproj.user` file in the project root directory.

[image]

Replacing the corrupted characters with the proper closing tag then reloading the project in VS restored functionality to the Publish button. It would have been nice to get some actual feedback from VS about this.

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: @J.DMallen, I've been dealing with this issue all this week.  Microsoft is really terrible at showing the reason why something won't publish.  I'm glad you found the answer

Comment: @johnny5 Happy to help!